# Data table not fitting correctly in Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, json, shiny, shinydashboard

I am having some trouble fitting a data table with a scroll feature in my shiny dashboard. Your help would be great.

```
  dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "Calendar",
          fluidRow(
          box(width = 2, height = 300,
            title = "Earnings Calendar",
            div(style = 'overflow-y: scroll',tableOutput("calendar"))
          )  
          )
          ),
  tabItem(tabName = "Earnigns"),
  tabItem(tabName = "Pre Earnings"),
  tabItem(tabName = "Scanner"),
  tabItem(tabName = "Contact")

  )
)
```

)
[image]

Comment: Can you provide sample data please

Comment: Thanks for the response Porky, I found the solution right here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505893/adding-a-vertical-and-horizontal-scoll-bar-to-the-dt-table-in-r-shiny

Comment: No worries lad!

Comment: maybe you can help me on the recent shiny question I asked tho :D